# Parsing comma separated strings with quotes and commas

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

```
+UULWM2MDM: 2,1,"3306/5/5851",11543,43,"{"bn":"/3306/5/5851","e":[{"n":"","v":85}]}",0
```

What is the best way to parse this so that I end up with the JSON string as a single item?

For example:

```
+UULWM2MDM: <int>,<int>,<string>,<int>,<int>,<json>,<int>
```

Can I do this with Regular Expression?

Comment: Fix whatever is producing that string so that the nested double quotes are properly quoted.

Comment: @chepner going straight to the point! I agree entirely, the solution to many issues is “avoid this problem in the first place”.

Comment: What is the expected output ? If rules can be applied, it can be parsed and fixed to some other set of rules.

Comment: This is not a good problem for regex to solve, because it appears to involve potentially arbitrary levels of nesting. JSON is not a regular language, and I agree with the posters above in saying that you'd be much better off properly parsing/cleaning it first before trying to attack it as a string with regex.